# Como Calcular CRC Modbus RTU

Tags: c, c++, checksum, microcontroladores-8bits

Estou tentando calcular um crc modbus em uma aplicação para PIC, mas o crc retornado esta sempre incorreto se comparado a simuladores online ..
segue o codigo

```
void CRC (unsigned char* msg, unsigned char* out)
{
    //char CRC16[2] = {0xFF,0xFF};
    unsigned int CRC16 = 0xffff; 
    unsigned int poly =  0xA001;
    unsigned char data[14];
    unsigned char crc [2];

    for (int i=0; i<14; i++)
    {   
        CRC16 = (unsigned int)msg[i] ^ CRC16; //alteração data para msg
        for (int j=0; j<8; j++)
        {  
            CRC16 >>= 1;

            if(CRC16 & 0x0001 == 1) 
            {
                CRC16 ^= poly; 
            }
        }
    }
    crc[0] = CRC16 >> 8;
    crc[1] = CRC16 & 0b0000000011111111 ;
    strcpy (data,msg);
    strcat (data,crc);
    strcpy (out,data);


}
```

eu entro com um buffer de 12 bytes para o calculo e no fim deve sair o buffer junto ao crc.. mas o calculo do crc em si esta retornando o valor errado.. o que pode estar errado no codigo?

no caso de minha mensagem deveria retrnar 8C0C mas retorna 68FE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está acontecendo devido à verificação do *LSB* estar após o *shift* do registador CRC16.

Essa verificação deve ocorrer antes da operação de shift, conforme o código modificado abaixo:

```
void CRC (unsigned char* msg, unsigned char* out)
{
    //char CRC16[2] = {0xFF,0xFF};
    unsigned int CRC16 = 0xffff;
    unsigned int poly =  0xA001;
    unsigned char data[14];
    unsigned char crc [2];

    for (int i=0; i<14; i++)
    {
        CRC16 = (unsigned int)msg[i] ^ CRC16; //alteração data para msg
        for (int j=0; j<8; j++)
        {
          // AQUI: primeiro verifica, depois executa o shift
          if(CRC16 & 0x0001 == 1)  {
            CRC16 >>= 1;
            CRC16 ^= poly;
          } else {
            CRC16 >>= 1;
          }
        }
    }
    crc[0] = CRC16 >> 8;
    crc[1] = CRC16 & 0b0000000011111111 ;
    strcpy (data,msg);
    strcat (data,crc);
    strcpy (out,data);
}
```

Referência (pdf): [MODBUS over Serial Line](http://modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf)